# Android drawing a custom view onDraw(). only draw a half of the image

Tags: android, view, android-canvas, ondraw

Im extending the View class in order to have a "drawable" view witch contains the desired background.

The problem is when this class works fine in other activity (same app).

Here is the class that extends View:

```
public class BackgroundMap extends View {

private String strmap;
private int totalWidth;

public BackgroundMap(Context context, String map, int w, int h) {
    super(context);
    super.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(w, h));
    totalWidth = w;
    strmap = map;

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Resources res = getResources();
    int eachBoxSize = totalWidth/10;
    float left = 0;
    float top = 0;

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    for(char c : strmap.toCharArray()){

        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, Terrain.getResource(c)), eachBoxSize, eachBoxSize, false);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, left, top, paint);

        if(left == totalWidth - eachBoxSize){
            left = 0;
            top += eachBoxSize; 
        }else{
            left += eachBoxSize;
        }

    }



}
```

}

This view works like this: somelayout.addView(new BackgroundMap(arg..));

the String map argument means an array of terrains (char) ids that point to several little png images.

and this is how i use it in my Activity:

```
ly_rbtn_image = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ly_rbtn_image);

        ly_rbtn_image.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                     imagewidth = ly_rbtn_image.getWidth();
                     ly_rbtn_image.addView(new BackgroundMap(getApplicationContext(), str, imagewidth, imagewidth));

            }
        });
```

i check with logcat the width of parent layout and it has 225px. As you can see the image  below only build the first row of bitmaps... but this IS NOT a loop problem

I check inside the custom view loop at onDraw method if there was a problem here but it iterate the whole string (100 chars, 10x10 bitmaps)

hope u can help me :S

http://deviantsart.com/1afcam8.png

Answer (score 1):

solved. please delete me.

the bitmaps were pushed at right till the end of the loop. So in fact, i didnt know why this happened.

UNTIL I CHECKED THE BOUNDS OF THE RESULT VIEW IN LOGCAT x))) the view had 2000 pixels width and 20 height... there we go:

When i get the total width of the device, casually was a number divisible by 10 (10x10 grid) so in fact was lucky not having this problem before (building the same map in other view).

Then, the problem was the need to print the same map (or grid) in an other view, not big as the device width, so the total width (parent width) was not divisible by the number of columns of the grid (im ashamed x)).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just FYI, that's not how this site works. The goal is to leave the questions and answers here, even when the problem is solved, to help other users.

Comment: I post my answer, sorry, ill edit in order to explain where is the problem accurately